# Modal get overlap behind the ipad virtual keypad

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad, keyboard

I am using a custom `ui-dialog` modal.  This is working fine on desktop and android device. But ON IOS device it's occurring issue once virtual keypad open. Usually, it's pushed the content top once keyboard shows. I have used `position: absolute;` and also tried with `relative` but still, it does not work. Can anybody help me with this..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<script>
if( navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i) ) {
   var s = document.createElement('style'), styleSheet;
   document.head.appendChild(s);
   styleSheet = s.sheet;
   styleSheet.insertRule(".modal { position:absolute; bottom:auto; }", 0);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not working for me. I have used also `max-height: calc(100vh - 160px);` but still issue is not solved.